# How to use native script in elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I followed steps -
1. created a class that implemented NativeScriptFactory.
2. created a class that extended AbstractSearchScript.

Examples:

1.

```
public class ExceptOperationScriptFactory implements NativeScriptFactory {
    public ExecutableScript newScript(Map<String, Object> params) {
        return new ExceptOperationScript(params);
    }
}
```

2.

```
public class ExceptOperationScript extends AbstractSearchScript {
     private static int counter = 0;
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     public ExceptOperationScript(Map<String, Object> params) {
         System.out.println(new Date()+ " -- Inside Constructor --  " + counter++);
     }
     public Object run() {
          System.out.println(new Date()+ " -- Inside run --  " + counter++);
          if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(field)) {
               Object value = null;
               if (source() != null)
                    value = source().get(field);
               else if (doc() != null)
                    value = doc().get(field);

               if (value != null)
                    System.out.println("BEFORE check value of Current document field's value :: " + value + "--"+ new Date());

          }
          return null;
     }
}
```

The output on the console  -

```
Fri Nov 21 23:09:12 PST 2014 -- Inside Constructor --  0
Fri Nov 21 23:09:12 PST 2014 -- Inside Constructor --  1
Fri Nov 21 23:09:12 PST 2014 -- Inside Constructor --  2
Fri Nov 21 23:09:12 PST 2014 -- Inside run --  3
Fri Nov 21 23:09:12 PST 2014 -- Inside run --  4
Fri Nov 21 23:09:12 PST 2014 -- Inside run --  5
Fri Nov 21 23:09:12 PST 2014 -- Inside Constructor --  6
Fri Nov 21 23:09:12 PST 2014 -- Inside Constructor --  7
Fri Nov 21 23:09:12 PST 2014 -- Inside run --  8
```

I am not able to track the flow here. Why there is random flow of calls?. 
According to me calls order should be Inside constructor and then Inside run.

How to solve this issue? Shall I make the method and constructor synchronized?

Answer (score 0):

You probably hit some threading here, i.e. Elasticsearch will spread out searches into multiple threads to make use of multiple CPU cores on single nodes. So the script is instantiated multiple times in parallel in multiple threads and depending on the CPU scheduling some instances of the script already start to run whereas others are still constructed.

tl;dr: As you have multiple threads the order of execution is undefined when things are started in parallel.